# two divs the same line, one dynamic width, one fixed

Tags: css, html

I have two divs under one parent `div`, the parent div has 100% width:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The conditions are:

- I want two divs on the same line.
- The right div may or may not be present. When it is present, I want it to always be fixed on the right. However, the left div must be elastic - it's width depends on its content.

I have tried both float:left, and dispaly:inline-block but neither solution seems to work.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I'd go with @sandeep's `display: table-cell` answer if you don't care about IE7.

Otherwise, here's an alternative, with one downside: the "right" `div` has to come first in the HTML.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/qLTMf/
and exactly the same, but with the "right div" removed: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/qLTMf/1/

```
#parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red
}
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #888;
}
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc
}
<div id="parent">
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam semper porta sem, at ultrices ante interdum at. Donec condimentum euismod consequat. Ut viverra lorem pretium nisi malesuada a vehicula urna aliquet. Proin at ante nec neque commodo bibendum. Cras bibendum egestas lacus, nec ullamcorper augue varius eget.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i know that trick & it's great http://htmldog.com/ is also implement in his own website but i want to make it according to @Yijie given markup

Comment: @sandeep: Yeah, I agree. I would have posted an answer based on `display: table-cell` myself if you hadn't already done so.

Comment: @thriydot; you also deserve +1 too

Comment: This solution works well, but I don't like the fact the left and right divs have a fixed height. What would the code look like if you wanted the divs to be the same (but dynamic) height with dynamic content in either of them?

Answer (score 15):

@Yijie; Check the link maybe that's you want http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/NCkL4/7/

**EDIT**:

http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/NCkL4/8/

**OR SEE THE FOLLOWING SNIPPET**

```css
#parent{
    overflow:hidden;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    display:table;
}
.left{
    display:table-cell;
}
.right{
    background:red;
    width:50px;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="right">fixed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what the poster wanted. If you remove the right div it will leave blank space, because you used padding to keep the content's distance.

Comment: @darthJDG & Yijie Li check my new jsfiddle maybe that's you want

Comment: `display: table-cell` is a good way to get the desired effect here, but you should be aware that it won't work in IE7. That fact may, or may not matter.

Comment: +1 That's nice, although you might want to test it in different browsers. Would you mind putting the actual code in your answer rather than just a link?

Comment: Yes, please always put a copy of the code in the answer, in case a link breaks or jsfiddle goes away, etc.

Answer (score 4):

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

(div.right needs to be before div.left in the HTML markup)

CSS:

```
.right {
float:right;
width:200px;
}
```

Comment: this is an interesting idea. but it doesnt work,,when the left div takes up the whole line, it goes under the right div.

Answer (score 0):

So left div style depends on the presence of right div. I can't think of a CSS selector allowing that kind of behavior yet.

Thus it seems to me that you'll need to programmatically add a class server side (or in JS) on parent div or left div to do that.

```
<div id="parent twocols">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

So right style is always :

```
.right {
    float: right;
    width: 200px; /* or whatever value you need */
    /* margin and padding at your discretion */
}
```

and left style is :

```
.parent.twocols .left {
    margin-right: 200px; /* according to right div width + margin + padding*/
}
```

Comment: when you use

    .left{margin-right:200px}

if the right div is not present. it will leave a blank space. won't it?

Comment: I am not using `.left{margin-right:200px}` but `.parent.twocols .left{margin-right:200px}` to only include this margin when the right column is present as indicated by the `.twocols` additionnal class

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with using white-space: nowrap; on the outer container, display: inline-block; on the inner containers, and then (in my case since I wanted the second one to word-wrap) white-space: normal; on the inner ones.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is you want:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#parent 
{width:100%;
height:100%;
border:1px solid red;
}
.left
{
float:left;
width:40%;
height:auto;
border:1px solid black;
}
.right
{
    float:left;

width:59%;
height:auto;
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  <div class="right">This is the right side content</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the demo:http://jsfiddle.net/anish/aFBmN/

Comment: That's not what the poster wanted. The right side is not fixed size, and if you remove the right div it leaves blank space.

Comment: thank you , but the same issue for 3 answers,,,when you remove right div,,it leaves blank space....I guess I will use script instead...