# Making a a DIV resize to min before shifting other DIV's position

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two divs one is filled with text and I want it to be fluid/responsive:

```
{
max-width: 600px;
min-width: 380px;
float: left;
}
```

I then have another div:

```
{
width: 340px;
float: left;
}
```

Wrapper is set to 960px when I have browser full screen the align up perfectly and it looks good.

What I want is when the browser window is resized that the first div resizes down and when it reaches its min-width the next div jumps down.

I realise it I may need @media queries I just have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Using this post I figured it out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056759/two-divs-the-same-line-one-dynamic-width-one-fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {   
    /* PUT THE CODE IN HERE */


    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    clear: both;

}
```

or use the html version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" href="css/phone.css" />
```

Then just put the code in there for the phone, or if you want a responsive lay-out
you should use percentages for the widths.