# How to design 2 divs on the same line, width fixed at left, responsive at right, and same height for the both

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a page with a timeline at left, and a text at right.
The both div has to have the same height (because each text is according to a specific date at left).

The difficulty is that i would like the left div to have a fixed width (i don't need the timeline to be responsive) and the right one (the text) to be responsive.

I was thinking `width: auto; display: inline-block;` for the responsive div would do the job, but if the text is too long, the div go to a new line and take 100% of the container.

So, it sounds really basic, but i don't see any way to achieve it without using javascript.

How would you do that (widht fixed at left, responsive at right, and same height for the both sides) ?

http://jsfiddle.net/N6VPn/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [two divs the same line, one dynamic width, one fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056759/two-divs-the-same-line-one-dynamic-width-one-fixed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Flex model to achieve that...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N6VPn/1/)

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
}

.left {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
}

.right {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

---

Not happy with the flex? Use `display: table;` for the parent element and set the child elements to `display: table-cell;`

```
.wrap {
    display: table;
}

.left {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: grey;
    display: table-cell;
}
.right {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N6VPn/2/)

Comment: I tried the both solutions, the first one (with flex) doesn't works for me (Chrome 26), but the second one works fine !

Comment: @Ludo Yea, the flex support isn't much, so I provided an alternate method as well :)