# div with inline-block not resizing

Tags: html, css

I have two elements, both with display: inline-block, and the parent has white-space: nowrap.

When the screen is resized, the div on the right side don't resize, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2e24.png).

I'm trying to make only the blue div resize.

[Full source](http://jsfiddle.net/F3mFe/) (jsfiddle)

The structure of the html is like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">...</div> <!-- red -->
    <div class="aside">...</div>  <!-- pink -->
    <article>...</article>        <!-- blue -->
</div>
```

Relevant css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 40em;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.container > * {
    white-space: normal;
}

.aside {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 15em;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.article {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 25em;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by resizing?

Comment: I meant it changes its size to follow the screen dimensions. The header in the image does that, but I'm trying to make the blue article do that as well.

Comment: Why would it resize? Why wouldn't the one of the left resize? You gave them a maximum width of which they apply to. If you want the one div to stay the same, and the second div to change, you'll have to use a small hack. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056759/two-divs-the-same-line-one-dynamic-width-one-fixed

Comment: @Narxx Hmm, I've seen your link, so basically put `float: left` on the `.aside`, `overflow: hidden` on the `article`, and `display: block` on both... That actually works. You could post that as an answer. I'd like to know if there's another way to do this though.

Comment: Yes. There are other ways. I used to work with negative margins on my last project. Works great! It's a bit of a hack, but it has its upsides :)
[Link](http://alistapart.com/article/negativemargins)

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but for the sake of knowledge of anyone who reads this and also has the doubt:

> What I've found is that setting position: relative on the .container
>   and position: absolute on the .article does what I want.

An **absolute positioned element** is positioned relative to *the nearest positioned ancestor*, where a positioned element means **anything with a position property different to static, the default**; if does not found any positioned element, uses the body element.

The absolute positioned elements, **if has their width and heigth in auto, resizes to fit its content, and limits the maximun sizes by its positioned ancestor**. You can check this putting a short string instead a large one: the element will shrink to the length of text. If you remove the positioning from div.container, the article (if still positioned absolute) will grow (depending on its content) to cover the space between previous element and body width.

And, related to the aforementioned and to add some utility to this delayed answer, a not-very-know bonus: if you define the right and left properties of a absoluted positioned element, and leave the width in auto, the element will cover the horizontal size between the right and left defined. This way you could put something like

```
article {
    background-color: #a0f4ec;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 30%;
}

div.aside {
    background-color: #faf;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 15em;
    width: 30%;
}
```

This trick also applies in a vertical sense, but with height, top and bottom properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it.
Method 1:
[two divs the same line, one dynamic width, one fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056759/two-divs-the-same-line-one-dynamic-width-one-fixed)

Method 2 (negative margins)
http://alistapart.com/article/negativemargins

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, both techniques need `float`. I'm trying to do it without them, sorry.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use `float`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Narxx's answers require the divs to be floated. I'm sure that's what you should do if you're building a real site, but in my case, I'm trying not to use it.

What I've found is that setting `position: relative` on the `.container` and `position: absolute` on the `.article` does what I want.

[Simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcJtH/)

If anyone can explain why, I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. What is it EXACTLY that you are trying to do?